# Blocks are blocking my view

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

suppose I do this:

```
MyClass *vista = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

vista.onFinish = ^{
    CGRect rect = vista.bounds;
    // bla bla bla
};
```

then xcode will award me with this error: capturing vista strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle

Someone suggested declaring vista like this

```
__unsafe_unretained MyClass *vista = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

but the problem is this. vista variable is assigned to a property a few lines down.

```
self.myVista = vista;
```

and this is a nonatomic, strong property.

How do I solve that? I can declare a temporary id var to use that, but this appears to be a lame solution.

Any thought?

Comment: Does `__weak MyClass *weak_vista = vista;` work?

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry, I see.

Comment: But creating a weak reference and using that inside the block should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MyClass *vista = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

__weak MyClass *weakVista = vista;    
vista.onFinish = ^{
    CGRect rect = weakVista.bounds;
    // bla bla bla
};
```